# How do I define a Unique Constraint in the "new" SQL Alchemy syntax?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How do I define a Unique Constraint using the "new" SQL Alchemy syntax.

This is what I have tried.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]

    UniqueConstraint('name')

    addresses: Mapped[List['Address']] = relationship(back_populates='user')
```

The `UniqueConstraint` has no effect. I don't doubt that this is because I am using the wrong style syntax. The documentation pages do not contain any information about how to do it using the new style syntax.

The style used here should be used as an input to defining a table using the

```
... = Table(
    ...
)
```

syntax.

[See documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/constraints.html).

Comment: Have you tried `name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)` ?

Comment: @GordThompson I didn't realize that was possible. What should I do in the case where a combination of columns should be unique, rather than a single one as in my (perhaps too simple) example?

Comment: You can use `__table_args__` for that. Example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-configuration).

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks, that looks like a good solution. One thing I am struggling a bit with when working with SQL Alchemy is the unusually large number of possible ways of implementing any one thing... For example, this describes yet another way of describing ForeignKeys. So what's the best way forward?